# Parallelism in Apache storm and telling the supervisors what to do

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm a total beginner with apache storm trying to write a basic program.  I set up a storm cluster with 3 supervisors.  The program I am trying to write is one that would have one supervisor add 0-99, another add 100-199, the third to add 200-299, and then have them push back to nimbus where each total is added together and then outputted to a file.  How do I make each of these loops, that will add the numbers, separate jobs that will go to different supervisors? The following is my code as of now but I just don't understand how storm from the code I've written would know to send the jobs different ways.

```
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.testing.TestWordSpout;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;

import java.util.Map;



public class AddNumMain{

public class addNumBolt{
    public int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, total = 0;

    public int addNums1(){  
        for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++)  // job 1
            a += i;
        return a;
    }
    public int addNums2(){  
        for(int j = 100; j < 199; j++)  // job 2
            b += j;
        return b;
    }
    public int addNums3(){  
        for(int t = 200; t < 299; jt++)  // job 3
            c += t;
        return c;
    }
    public int total(){
        total = a + b + c;
        return total;
    }
}

public static void main(){
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();



    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);
    conf.setNumWorkers(3);

    StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(args[0],  conf,  builder.createTopology());

    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluser.submitTopology("myTopology", comf, builder.createTopology()); // need to add parameters
    Utils.sleep(10000); //runs for 10 seconds before shutting cluster down
    cluster.killTopology("myTopology");
    cluster.shutdown();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: I just added the code i've written so far. @JFPicard

Comment: supervisor/nimbus are just the daemons. the actual component used in storms are `Spout` & `Bolt`. Nimbus doesnot perform any execution of logic. So `... have them push back to nimbus where each total is added together` doesn't make much sense . I suppose it would really be useful if you take a look at the storm documentation and edit your questions accordingly. Also take a look at what is the difference between `LocalCluster` and `StormSubmitter`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking as Supervisor as a job executor.this is not the case.
Nimbus,supervisor ,zookeeper are are daemons. they are not real job executor.

Spout and bolts are the real executors which runs inside the JVM. so if u want to do the division of the work as mentioned 0-99.. etc.. you have to split the stream using field grouping on 1 of the bolt and send the stream to 3 bolts.

and 1 more info Supervisor will take care of the the running the workers (JVM).